# Can't get namespace to display correctly in soap response from Spring Web Service

Tags: java, spring, soap, marshalling

I cant seem to get rid of the ns0 from the root.  What am I doing wrong?

Interceptor

```
@Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {

        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();

        try {
            SOAPMessage saajMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");
            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addNamespaceDeclaration("ims", "http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p");
            saajMessage.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Correct**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ims="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0">
```

**Incorrect**

```
<soapenv:Envelope ns0:ims="ims" xmlns:ns0="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by updating the order

```
try {
            SOAPMessage saajMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();

            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");
            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addNamespaceDeclaration("ims", "http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p");
            saajMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soapenv");
            saajMessage.saveChanges();
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```